# jquery mobile options in selectBox are not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

Hi the options in jqueryMobile select are not rendering properly.
Below is the jsfiddle

```
Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/DjsWv/14/)!
```

[image]

You can see option:2012 is not rendered properly in chrome.
Like height few times width also creating problems.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Add this style `#select-choice-year{font-size:15px;}` http://jsfiddle.net/DjsWv/16/

Comment: Fine. I have posted the above solution as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Style in your CSS.

```
 #select-choice-year{font-size:15px;}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DjsWv/16/)